# What happens to parts or materials taken off of (true) polymorphed creatures?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, polymorph

As a DM with a wizard PC dangerously close to asking me that question I figured I'd try and find some primary source on this.

Neither *[True Polymorph](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-polymorph)* nor *[Polymorph](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/polymorph)* state what happens to bits and pieces that detach from a polymorphed (or true polymorphed) creature prior to it "dying".

A plan my players off-handedly discussed was True-polymorphing a party member into a [young black dragon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/young-black-dragon) and harvesting his blood for a half-dragon ritual.

Are there any official sources (also accepting older editions) that specify what happens to the true polymorph-sourced blood in this scenario?

Does any source make a distinction between what happens with Lvl 4 polymorphed vs Lvl 9 true polymorphed (and perhaps even permanent) parts?